# Tiempos consulta con Guzzle supuesta mente en paralelo no funciona

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy tratando de consultar varios webservices diferentes en paralelo con `Guzzle` (en `laravel`), pero cuando tomo tiempos, entiendo que los esta realizando secuencialmente, uno a uno, en vez de todos juntos y a la vez.
La consulta individual a un solo webservice, el que mas tarda, me toma 4 segundos, lo cual entiendo que al ser en paralelo, debería ser el tiempo máximo. En vez de ello, al hacer 3 `request`, obtengo una demora de 12 segundos al consultar 3 `webservices`.
Estoy usando `Guzzle` con promesas, pero no se si es el modo adecuado.

Este es mi código:

```
$client = new Client();

$promises['resultado1']= $client->postAsync('http://undominio.com',['headers' => $headers,'body' => $body]);

$promises['resultado2']= $client->postAsync('http://otrodominiodiferentealprimero',['headers' => $headers,'body' => $body]);

$promises['resultado3']= $client->postAsync('http://untercerdominiodiferenteatodos',['headers' => $headers,'body' => $body]);

$results = Promise\settle($promises)->wait();
```

Comment: Qué versión de PHP estás usando? Tienes instalada la extensión php-curl?

Answer (score 1):

Se supone que al inicializar `$client` con `new GuzzleHttp\Client()` si no le pasas un `handler` explícito,  la instancia de client elige el mejor `handler` por ti.

Cuando no tienes instalado `curl` o `php-curl` el handler por defecto es [StreamHandler](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php).

Pensemos en un endpoint `endpoint.php` que recibe como parámetro un tiempo y responde después de ese tiempo

```
<?php
//endpoint.php    
sleep($_GET['wait']);
echo 'listo';
```

De acuerdo a la [documentación de Handlers](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/handlers-and-middleware.html#handlers), Si tú usaras explícitamente el `StreamHandler`

```
$handler = new \GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler();
$stack   = \GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack::create($handler); 
$client  = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['handler' => $stack]);

$tini                = time();
$promises            = [];
$promises['demora3'] = $client->getAsync('http://sitio.com/endpoint.php?wait=3');
$promises['demora2'] = $client->getAsync('http://sitio.com/endpoint.php?wait=2');
$promises['demora1'] = $client->getAsync('http://sitio.com/endpoint.php?wait=1');

$promises['demora3']->then(function ($res) use ($tini) {
    echo '<br> demora3: demoró ' . (time() - $tini) . ' segundos ';
});
$promises['demora2']->then(function ($res) use ($tini) {
    echo '<br> demora2: demoró ' . (time() - $tini) . ' segundos ';
});
$promises['demora1']->then(function ($res) use ($tini) {
    echo '<br> demora1: demoró ' . (time() - $tini) . ' segundos ';
});

$results = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\settle($promises)->wait();
```

Los requests se resolverían en forma síncrona y el resultado sería:

```
demora3: demoró 6 segundos 
demora2: demoró 6 segundos 
demora1: demoró 6 segundos
```

Porque se demoraron 1+2+3 segundos en total.

Para lograr lo que quieres, tendrías que tener instalado `curl` en tu sistema, y la extensión `php-curl`, y para más seguridad, decirle explícitamente que quieres usar [CurlMultiHandler](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Handler/CurlMultiHandler.php).

```
$handler = new \GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler();
$stack   = \GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack::create($handler); 
$client  = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['handler' => $stack]);

$tini                = time();
$promises            = [];
$promises['demora3'] = $client->getAsync('http://sitio.com/endpoint.php?wait=3');
$promises['demora2'] = $client->getAsync('http://sitio.com/endpoint.php?wait=2');
$promises['demora1'] = $client->getAsync('http://sitio.com/endpoint.php?wait=1');

$promises['demora3']->then(function ($res) use ($tini) {
    echo '<br> demora3: demoró ' . (time() - $tini) . ' segundos ';
});
$promises['demora2']->then(function ($res) use ($tini) {
    echo '<br> demora2: demoró ' . (time() - $tini) . ' segundos ';
});
$promises['demora1']->then(function ($res) use ($tini) {
    echo '<br> demora1: demoró ' . (time() - $tini) . ' segundos ';
});

$results = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\settle($promises)->wait();
```

Y debieras obtener:

```
demora1: demoró 1 segundos 
demora2: demoró 2 segundos 
demora3: demoró 3 segundos
```

Comment: gracias!, voy a probar el codigo y generar los test correspondientes.